# Is there a way to expand/contract UITableViewCells on the fly?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, resize

I would like to have a custom UITableViewCell that displays limited data while unselected, but then expand to show more details when selected.

The issue I have is how do I adjust the size of the cell during a select/deselect event?

Comment: Asked many times. Search for "expand cells".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing it not so long ago. To adjust the size you need to make `UITableView` call `heightForRowAtIndexPath` again. It will cause redrawing of cell. Use

```
- (void)reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation
```

in order to do that. If you set animation to `YES` it will nicely animate expanding of your cell. Also to adjust cell, `setSelected:` in your `UITableViewCell` subclass may be helpfull.

Answer (score 1):

Make a sub-class of UITableViewCell, and override the drawRect() method.
In your view controller's didSelectRowAtIndexPath, you can switch between the contracted and expanded states.  You can change frame sizes, add or remove sub-views, add more data, whatever you need to do.